# Facebook App: Firebase Simple Login URL error

Tags: facebook, localhost, firebase, facebook-login, firebasesimplelogin

I am trying to make my first app using Facebook login and the Firebase Simple Login. I am running the system locally on `http://localhost:8000/`. The error I am receiving upon clicking the login button is below.

> "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains."

I have tried running it on a production facebook app and a facebook test app as well as added URL redirects and website platforms following other forum post I have seen, but nothing is working for me. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add `localhost` to the Authorized Request Origins in the Simply Login section of your Firebase dashboard?

Comment: Yes. I added localhost in Firebase and Facebook App.

Comment: This error is coming from Facebook. The URLs entered in Facebook app config are not correct.

Comment: I have tried all possible configurations of the app config and I am not having any luck. Has anyone done this configuration recently?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I discovered in the Firebase documentation that `https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback` must be input into the Valid OAuth redirect URIs under the advanced settings.

Recap of Facebook Test App Settings:

Under Basic App Settings:
Domain = `localhost:8080`
URL = `http://localhost:8080`

Under Advanced App Settings:
Valid OAuth redirect URIs [`http://localhost:8080/` ; `https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback`]

Comment: Nice! I spent ages setting it up because in the firebase doc. stays: In your Facebook app configuration, click on the Settings tab on the left-hand navigation menu. Then go to the Advanced tab at the top and scroll down to the Security section. At the bottom of that section, add https://auth.firebase.com/v2/<YOUR-FIREBASE>/auth/facebook/callback to your Valid OAuth redirect URIs and click Save Changes at the bottom of the page.

hm...

Comment: https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback <---- added this and it worked. I don't know why the document only asked to add auth.firebase.com/v2/<YOUR-FIREBASE>/auth/facebook/ , but it didn't work

Comment: FWIW, I had to do *both* (v2 and the standard)

Answer (score 4):

with newest version, Valid OAuth redirect must be set as : https://.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler