# Facebook returning error message when using Firebase Login

Tags: facebook, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use a Firebase Facebook login in the following way:

Added this to my HTML (to test):

```
<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

and the firebase script:

`<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.5/firebase.js"></script>`

This in my module:

`var app = angular.module('myApp' ['firebase']);`

and then inside my controller:

```
controller('yokoAppCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth, wordsFactory){
  var ref = new Firebase("https://resplendent-fire-4284.firebaseio.com/data");

  // download the data into a local object
  var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
  // synchronize the object with a three-way data binding
  // click on `index.html` above to see it used in the DOM!
  syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");


  // create an instance of the authentication service
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  // login with Facebook
  auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook").then(function(authData) {
    console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Authentication failed:", error);
  });
})
```

When I reload the page in `localhost:8000` I get the following message from Facebook:

`Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

I followed the Firebase docs and this stackoverflow url: [Facebook App: Firebase Simple Login URL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225280/facebook-app-firebase-simple-login-url-error) but I am still lost.

Under Site URL my app has `http://localhost:8000/`, I also tried to include under domain name `localhost:8000` but Facebook removes it saying `"No Top-Level Domains allowed"`. This is all under "Basic" Settings.
Under "Advanced" I have the following under `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`:

`https://auth.firebase.com/v2/<myFirebase>/auth/facebook/callback
http://localhost:8080/
https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback`

and I already enabled Facebook connection in Firebase. What am I missing?

Comment: Double-check that you entered the correct "Valid OAuth redirect URI" for your Firebase app in the App > Settings > Advanced tab of your Facebook app on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/. This is documented in the seocnd paragraph of the Firebase documentation for Facebook authentication on https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? Because I am getting the same error even after performing all the required steps.

Comment: @Yatin did you manage to solve this? I'm having trouble setting up Firebase with Facebook. I'm not sure why its not working. I added the correct url in the advance security settings of my facebook app.

Comment: No AngularM, It didn't work for me. If you figure out something then plz let me know also