# com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Provider error - Firebase-UI Authentication Facebook login not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, facebook-authentication

I am using Firebase-UI authentication using e-mail, facebook, and google providers. E-mail and Google sign in work fine but Facebook sign in is not working.

My facebook and firebase dependencies:

```
//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

//Cloud Firestore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'

//Firebase Authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'

//Firebase built-in Auth UI
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'

//Firebase Storage
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'

// Required only if Facebook login support is required
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'

//Google sign-in with Firebase Authentication
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

The necessary facebook strings:

```
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">#######</string>
<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fb#######</string>
```

In my activity I have:

```
void signIn() {
    AuthUI.IdpConfig facebookIdpConfig = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder()
            .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends"))
            .build();
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
            facebookIdpConfig);

    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setTheme(AuthUI.getDefaultTheme())
                    .setLogo(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_login_logo)
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Before clicking Facebook sign in button: 
[Sign in buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCgmy.png)

After clicking Facebook sign in button:
[Error page after clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg1Tf.png)

Error log after closing the Facebook error page:

```
07-16 14:23:43.480 27301-27301/com.example E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Provider error
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.FacebookSignInHandler$Callback.onError(FacebookSignInHandler.java:117)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.FacebookSignInHandler$Callback.onCancel(FacebookSignInHandler.java:112)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:654)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:245)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:174)
        at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:95)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.FacebookSignInHandler.onActivityResult(FacebookSignInHandler.java:87)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.AuthMethodPickerActivity.onActivityResult(AuthMethodPickerActivity.java:225)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: null
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.FacebookSignInHandler$Callback.onCancel(FacebookSignInHandler.java:112) 
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:654) 
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:245) 
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:174) 
        at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:95) 
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.FacebookSignInHandler.onActivityResult(FacebookSignInHandler.java:87) 
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.AuthMethodPickerActivity.onActivityResult(AuthMethodPickerActivity.java:225) 
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
07-16 14:23:43.485 27301-27301/com.gamifymykid.gamifymykid E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Provider error
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.FacebookSignInHandler$Callback.onError(FacebookSignInHandler.java:117)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.FacebookSignInHandler$Callback.onCancel(FacebookSignInHandler.java:112)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:654)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:245)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:174)
        at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:95)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.FacebookSignInHandler.onActivityResult(FacebookSignInHandler.java:87)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.AuthMethodPickerActivity.onActivityResult(AuthMethodPickerActivity.java:225)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have searched other questions who have had problems similar to mine but their answers do not solve my problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseUI authentication with Facebook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468316/firebaseui-authentication-with-facebook-not-working)

Answer (score 8):

When you use this command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

to get the Key Hashes you put in facebook configurations, it will ask you for a password, make sure you enter `android` as the password.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the configurations, it's working on higher Android APIs

Comment: It's imperative you use "android" as the password... I was trying to use some other personal password and it wouldn't work. Thanks, it's working for me.

Comment: already did this ..but it gives error like this `com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Developer error`

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable facebook sign In In firebase?

Check your app id and App secret key is the same as developer.facebook.com

In developer.facebook.com go to your app, And then Setting->Basic
Check App Id and App Secret is same as facebook SignIn in firebase

Also, don't forget to add outh Url in your app in the Facebook developer page